# Regular Expression Nightmare

Tags: c#, asp.net

Does anyone know the regular expression for this following format in C#: yyyy/mm/dd
This regular expression stuff is really doing my head in, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html

Answer (score 8):

Why not simply use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) ?

A simple regex won't deal with invalid dates ,  months or days.

Comment: True, I might have to do something like that. It seems to filter out most stuff though, didn't work with feb 30th like mrmuggles said.

Answer (score 2):

Check this answer:
[YYYYMMDD Date Format regular Expression to validate a date in C# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766845/yyyymmdd-date-format-regular-expression-to-validate-a-date-in-c-sharp-net)

I don't think regular expression is a good idea as it will not catch "bad dates" like february 30th etc...

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do here? `\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}` will match "four-digits-slash-two-digits-slash-two-digits", but I suspect you're looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
$[1-9][0-9]{3}/(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
```

But as someone else suggest, you shouldn't solve this with regex. I haven't tried my solution but I already see a bug with Februar for example. And how do you handle leap year with a regex?