# Java regex yyyymmdd validation

Tags: java, regex

Please help me why this regex is not working when it comes to date 20 in all years.But it works if I take date alone as seperate Regex.thanks in Advance.

```
String regex = "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?" ;  
checkRegex("02", regex);
checkRegex("22", regex);
checkRegex("20", regex);

String regex1 = "^(((19\\d\\d)|([2-9]\\d\\d\\d))\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?" ;    

checkRegex("19990802", regex1);
checkRegex("19990822", regex1);
checkRegex("19990820", regex1);
```

**Output :**

```
02::::^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::true
22::::^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::true
20::::^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::true
19990802::::^(((19\d\d)|([2-9]\d\d\d))\d\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::true
19990822::::^(((19\d\d)|([2-9]\d\d\d))\d\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::true
19990820::::^(((19\d\d)|([2-9]\d\d\d))\d\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?::::false
```

Comment: downvoters pls comment.

Comment: you can find a working regex here...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766845/yyyymmdd-date-format-regular-expression-to-validate-a-date-in-c-sharp-net

but as some of the answer says, not recommended to use regex for that...

Comment: who are you to insist me not to use if it works I will use.If you dont like simply leave dont try to find fault in others.If you have knowledge solve the problem first.The link you have shown is nothing to do with my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting a 10-digit number, not an 8-digit one.  You have an extra `\\d\\d` in the middle of your expression.

```
^(((19\\d\\d)|([2-9]\\d\\d\\d))\\d\\d)(0?[1-9]|1[012])(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])?
                               ^^^^^^
                                Here
```

Note that some 7, 8 and 9-digit numbers will be accepted by your regular expression, for two reasons.

1. You've made the `0`s optional at the beginning of the month, and the beginning of the day, by way of the `?` after each `0`.
2. You've made the day itself optional, by way of the `?` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
String regex1 = [0-9]{4}[0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9]
```

I recommend you to use:

```
string date= "19990820";
DateTime theTime= DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```